# IntelliJ keep asking for "Setup Scala SDK" after every synch with the repository

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

As the title says, IntelliJ keep asking to set the Scala SDK of my sbt projects (they are inside a multi-project) at every merge with the repository. It's like some settings file is being overwritten for a specific project but I can't seem to find what's the problem. Any insight on where to look?

Comment: How the `.gitignore` looks like?

Comment: I used a template and all the intellij-related stuff is ignored. 
I have *.iml, .idea/, *.ipr,*.iws, /out/, .idea_modules/

Answer (score 7):

If in the "Project Settings" (⌘-;) you have the `scala-jdk` set in the "Global Libraries":

[image]

and the problem persists, then I would suggest to try to:

- close the project and exit IntelliJ
- delete the `.idea` folder and
- create a new IntelliJ project importing the directory with the sbt-multiproject folders

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and complete new import did not help. I guess its a problem with multiple gradle modules where only one of them actually is in scala

Comment: I would add to Filippo's answer: Remove the sdk and add it back again. When intellij asks which modules will use the sdk, make sure you select all of the modules before clicking on Ok.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @corindiano , it sounds like a different answer I would `+1` ;-)